# BackgroundWorker does not fire inside User Control

Tags: c#

I am currently creating a Windows Form Application and I am wanting to use a BackgroundWorker.  I have created a very simple example which works perfectly:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bgw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(DoWork);
        bgw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
        bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            bgw.ReportProgress(i * 10, i.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    private void ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = string.Format("{0}% : Message = '{1}'", e.ProgressPercentage, e.UserState.ToString());
    }

    private void Completed(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Completed");
    }
}
```

Now, when I move the same code to my current application it does not fire.  The only difference is that instead of running the code at the Form level, I am attempting to run it inside a custom User Control.  As such:

```
public partial class LobbyForm : UserControl
{
    private BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();

    public LobbyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bgw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(DoWork);
        bgw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
        bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
    }

    public LobbyForm(List<TaskFile> tasks)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            bgw.ReportProgress(i * 10, i.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    private void ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        label5.Text = string.Format("{0}% : Message = '{1}'", e.ProgressPercentage, e.UserState.ToString());
    }

    private void Completed(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Completed");
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on if I am missing something?  Perhaps something I am misunderstanding with attempting to run this from a User Control?

Comment: You have two constructors with different initialization code.  Why?  When you run the 2nd constructor the backgroundworker events don't get registered.

Comment: How are you creating the UserControl ? Drag-Drop through designer ? or created in code ? If in code, plz show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just copied your code and tested it and it worked perfectly if you drag-drop the user control using the designer.

However, if you create he control at runtime and add it to your form, make sure you're using the correct constructor.

```
LobbyForm lf = new LobbyForm();
```

this runs this constructor:

```
public LobbyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    bgw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(DoWork);
    bgw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
    bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
}
```

and not

```
LobbyForm lf = new LobbyForm(tasks);
```

which runs this constructor (that doesn't hook up events):

```
public LobbyForm(List<string> tasks)
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

**Solution (Call the default constructor from the second one)**

```
public LobbyForm(List<string> tasks) : this()
{
    //InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: A good eye!  Seems I completely forgot i had overloaded the constructor.